# Button not submitting when changing attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a login system with only 1 button for "login" and "sign up".

```
<button type="submit" form="LoginForm" id="login"></button>
```

When I switch to sign up I change the button attribute and vice versa:

```
function showSignUp(){
document.getElementById('username').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('mail').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('password').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('password-repeat').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('token').style.display = "none";

document.getElementById('login').setAttribute("name","signup");
document.getElementById('login').setAttribute("value","signup");
}

            <label for="rdo-signup" class="btn-radio">
                <input type="radio" id="rdo-signup" name="radio-grp" onclick="showSignUp()">
...
```

the problem is that `$_POST['signup']` is empty when i submit the form.

It does work when I load the PHP with `name="login" value="login"` in the HTML attribute, but as soon as I change to signup again, it doesn't work anymore.

I'm kinda sure I'm f*ing up something because of serverside code and clientside changes, but I can't figure out how to change/fix this?

**[SOLUTION]**

the problem was the required fields. even if they're hidden, they still won't let me submit until i fill them.

Comment: Show the code where you change from login to signup and vice versa. You're likely not targetting the elements correctly. Though I don't see why you can just have separate buttons for this, and show/hide them as needed.

Comment: Don't mess things just make two buttons and display none and block on change form.

Comment: @Qirel i just updated the code. there is only one button because it's a design element wich has an animation on it. at no time the animation must be stopped. that's why i'm using only one button.

Comment: Better if you change only value attribute and check value at $_POST , is it login or singup? and  work accordingly.

Comment: you should not use setAttribute to set value. `document.getElementById('login').value="signup"` Just find it weird you do not use the radio button value to see if it is sign up or login. Adding a class to the form would be easier that showing hide a bunch of elements in the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a similar design and got it working. Please have a look the code below.
Hope that helps

HTML Form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showSignUp(){
            document.getElementById('username').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('mail').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('password').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('password-repeat').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('token').style.display = "none";

            document.getElementById('login').setAttribute("name","signup");
            document.getElementById('login').setAttribute("value","signup");
        }
    </script>

    <form action="form.php" method="POST" id="LoginForm">
        <input type="text" name="user" id="username" placeholder="username"><br><hr>
        <input type="mail" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="mail"><br><hr>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"><br><hr>
        <input type="password" name="password-repeat" id="password-repeat" placeholder="confirm password"><br><hr>
        <input type="text" name="token" id="token" placeholder="token"><br><hr>

        <button type="submit" form="LoginForm" id="login" name="login" value="login">login</button>
        <button type="button" id="change">signup</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('change').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('login').setAttribute('name','signup'); 
            document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = 'signup'; 
            document.getElementById('login').setAttribute('value','signup');
        }
    </script>
```

PHP Action:

```
<?php
echo $_POST["signup"];
echo $_POST["login"];
?>
```